# Concatenate string to list of numbers repeating the string each time (Python)

Tags: python, list, copy

I have a list of numbers, `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and I would like to attach the word `foo` in front of each number to get a string each time to get

```
['foo0','foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4',
 'foo5','foo6','foo7','foo8','foo9']
```

a function like `paste0('foo',0:9)` in R.

Comment: `['foo' + str(i) for i in range(9)]`?

Comment: If you need it in *R*, please tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list comprehension (credit: Barmar):
`['foo' + str(i) for i in range(9)]`

Using map:
`list(map(lambda i: 'foo' + str(i), range(9)))`

Using f-strings:
`[f'foo{i}' for i in range(9)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *for-loop* with the *[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)* built-in function.

```py
strings = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for index, value in enumerate(strings):
    strings[index] = "foo" + str(value)
```

Output

```
['foo0', 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5', 'foo6', 'foo7', 'foo8', 'foo9']
```

Comment: both `str(value)` and `str(index)` work, which is quite fun 

Answer (score 1):

You could use map and format to build the resulting list :

```
N = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

*foos, = map("foo{}".format,N)

print(foos)

['foo0','foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4','foo5','foo6','foo7','foo8','foo9']
```

If you want to do it "in-place" in the original list, you can assign the mapping to a subscript:

```
N[:] = map("foo{}".format,N)
```